# Model inside a template of a custom directive never updated

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple custom directive `myElement` with a templateUrl that print a simple message:

```
<p>Message: {{message}}</p>
```

Here's the definition of my directive:

```
testapp.directive('myElement', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p>Message: {{message}}</p>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.message = 'This message is never updated... :(';
            setTimeout(function() {
                scope.message = "Why this message is never shown?";
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
});
```

After 1 second, I expect an update of the message to "Why this message is never shown?". Unfortunately, the message is never updated.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seyz/SNMfc

Could you explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `scope.$apply();`

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    scope.message = "Why this message is never shown?";
    scope.$apply();
}, 1000);
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply):

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries).

Answer (score 4):

Due to how Angular dirty checking works, when you execute code outside of angular scope (e.g. using setTimeout, setInterval, or from within some third-party plugin callback) the changes produced by that code invocation won't be 'recognized' immediately by Angular scope.

For such scenarios you need to wrap your code inside the [scope.$apply()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) method.

In this particular case you may simply use [$timeout function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) to replace your `setTimeout(fn, 1000)`call with `$timeout(fn, 1000)`and your code will be wrapped with scope.$apply() call ([Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/adibih/eXEMB/)).

Comment: This is the recommended way. While Trevor Senior's answer is the general way you should do it when "outside" angular world, whenever you can you should angular's built in services

Comment: Yeah exactly, thanks for the answer. However, my code was a simple example to illustrate my real issue. `setTimeout` was just an example and so, I didn't really use it (if I need, I use `$timeout`). But really, thanks!